# closures with two inner functions python

Tags: python, closures

I am trying to write a closure with two inner functions, but I am getting the below error

```
def factory(n=0):
#n=0

    def current():
       return n
    return current
    def counter():
        n=n+1
        return n
    return counter


  f_current,f_counter = int(input())

  print(f_counter())
  print(f_current())
```

I have the below error:

```
   >>4
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/lokesh/Desktop/python/closure3.py", 
    line 13, in <module>
   f_current,f_counter = int(input())
   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

My requirement is after giving input 4,it should display:

```
  4
  5
```

I am new to python, can somebody help me here... thanks in advance

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with the title. What are you expecting `f_current,f_counter = int(input())` to do? You explicitly make the input a number, then you try to extract two values out of the number. And then you try to call the extracted numbers as functions, and you're missing a brace on the last line. This is too broad; there far too much wrong here.

Comment: How does `f_current` relate to `factory(n)`?

Comment: Pretty sure your indentation is off somewhere, but I'm not certain enough of your intent to say where. Did you mean to `return current, count`?

Comment: Also, I don't think you meant to define input parameters to the nested functions since you talk about closures. Take a look at LEGB and the `nonlocal` keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks more like what you want:

```
def factory(n=0):

    def current():
        return n

    def counter():
        nonlocal n
        n += 1
        return n

    return current, counter

f_current, f_counter = factory()

print(f_current())
print(f_counter())
print(f_current())
print(f_counter())
```

Output:

```
0
1
1
2
```

With `4` as input:

```
f_current, f_counter = factory(4)
print(f_current())
print(f_counter())

4
5
```

`factory()` returns both inner functions. You need to use `nonlocal` to increment the `n` form the enclosing function. Without `nonlocal` you would not be able to modify `n` but would get:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment
```

because `n` is just a local variable. `nonlocal n` makes `n` from the enclosing function modifiable inside the inner function. Assessing `n` in `current` is fine, because Python's scoping rules allow read access to variables form an outer scope, here from the scope of the enclosing function.

Comment: Thank you Mike... can you tell me what is meant by nonlocal?

Comment: A `nonlocal` name is a name in the locals of a surrounding function.  The declaration is needed to rebind a name in a surrounding function scope.  The `current` function does not need the declaration because it only reads `n` and does not assign to `n`.  (The keyword may seem odd, but was the choice after months of debate that delayed adding the option to do what it does.)

Answer (score 0):

> Hi Mike ,I think non-local does'nt make any sense,I am giving the
>   solution which worked in my case.

```
def factory(n):

    def current():

        return n

    def counter():

        n=int(current())
        n=n+1
        return n

    return current, counter
n=0
f_current, f_counter = factory((input()))

print(f_current())
print(f_counter())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def factory(n=0):

    def current():
        return n

    def counter():
        return n+1

    return current, counter

f_current, f_counter = factory(int(input()))

print(f_current())
print(f_counter())
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Mike's Nonlocal usage is very nice,but we can also access the variable value of n from enclosing scope by a new variable m inside Counter inner function and return it after incrementing.In that way,Nonlocal is not needed.

```
        def factory(n=0):
            def current():
                return n

            def counter():
                 m=n
                 m=m+1
                 return m

            return current,counter

         f_current,f_counter=factory(int(input()))

         print(f_current())
         print(f_counter())
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a new variable as the argument for the inner function which is equal to that of the outer function and proceed.

```py
def factory(n=0):
    def current():
        return n

    def counter(x=n):
        return x+1

    return current, counter

f_current,f_counter =factory(int(input()))

print(f_current())

print(f_counter())
```